# How to specify a default value for an argument for clap_app! macro?

Tags: rust, command-line-arguments, clap

I want to use `clap_app!` macro to define an argument which should have a default value. Unfortunately, there is nothing in the docs, and my naive attempt didn't work:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate clap;

fn main() {
    let matches = clap_app!(myapp =>
        (@arg seconds: -u +takes_value +default_value("1.0") "Update time")
    ).get_matches();
    println!("{}", matches.value_of("seconds").unwrap())
}
```

How can I specify a default value for an argument within `clap_app!` macro?

Comment: Why not just use `unwrap_or`?

Comment: I can, but then I need to use it every time I access value and I need to keep consistent about default value itself (If I ever decide to change it I'll need to change it in many places).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently impossible with number, https://github.com/kbknapp/clap-rs/issues/1035.

But it's should be:

```
(@arg seconds: -u +takes_value default_value[1.0] "Update time")
```

Comment: Oh! I shouldn't use `+` sign. `default_value("2.0")` worked for string.